# Objective C, How to make a active view to be appeared on the top notification menu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

If you open up the iPhone email application, a active view appears on the top of the notification menu next to the Wifi icon. How can I do this?

Comment: You mean the spinner next to the Wi-Fi icon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
```

Comment: `setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` is depracated
http://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623102-networkactivityindicatorvisible

Answer (score 0):

And changed to

```
UIApplication.shared().isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true / false
```

in swift 3. Xcode gently guides you from the former to new newer.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 9.1 and Swift 4 and `shared` is still a property not a method, therefore your answer is not up to date or it's just wrong.

Comment: @VSG24 There have benn many changes to the Swift language since it was release so it is quite impossible to keep all answers up to date with the latest version. Maybe it will stabilize with the current version four.

Answer (score 0):

**XCode 8 final, Swift 3:**

`UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true`